# How can I get selected item title and description in monodroid?

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I create Test Adapter and set items to ListView

```
 objListView.Adapter = new TestAdapter(this, this, objItems);
```

and I try to get clicked item title

```
     .
     .
     .
     objListView.ItemClick += new EventHandler<AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs>(objListView_ItemClick);


    void objListView_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        // how can I get Item title  ?          
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your implementation of TestAdapter, you should have a method called GetItemId to get the id of that object, or you could have your own method return the selected object like:

```
public YourObject GetObject(int position)
{ 
    return this.objItems.ElementAt(position)
}
```

And then, in your objListView_ItemClick method, you could make use of GetObject method to get the data. Next, create a new Intent instance and use PutExtra(string name, object o) to pass data to the Activity.

```
void objListView_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    var item= ((TestAdapter)objListView.Adapter).GetObject(e.position);
    var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(YourActivity));
    intent.PutExtra("Name", item.Title);
    intent.PutExtra("Description", item.Description);
    //Do whatever you want next.
}
```